# $('img').show("slide", direction: "right",500) changing position of img

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I use this function to animate my image:

```
$('img').show("slide", direction: "right",500);
```

Animate works but it changing my `img` position to top. `img` has

```
style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; margin:auto; left:0;"
```

so it's vertically centered. I noticed that while animation is going then `img` is transform to `div` and change `style`. I guess is the reason of my problem. So how to resolve this?

Regards

Comment: That code works? Looks like it is missing some `{` and `}` characters

Comment: Have you tried using CSS for animation? You dont need Javascript then.

Comment: Sorry i forget add {} in question :P Animation works but same problem.
You mean Canvas from CSS3? Anyway i like to know how to resolve this problem in JS if its possible :)

Comment: and what about trying to first show it and right after make the animation like: `$("img").show().animate{"right": "+=500"}` ? I never made an animation inside a `show()`.

Comment: @Cheshire you are missing brackets : `$("img").show().animate({"right": "+=500"});`

Comment: true, may fault there, but give it a try

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to animate this to the right 500 more pixels than it already is without modifying the `top` style of the image, and if that's the case, then this will do exactly that

```
$('img').show().animate({
    'left':'+500px'   
}, 'slide');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fL1o3wab/3/

Comment: Effect is different than using "slide" inside show(). In my animation img not show whole of them immediately but appear as for the wall.

Comment: You can add easing types such as "slide" to the `animate()` function by setting it as one of the parameters, such as how I've done it in my updated answer. If you're still having problems, then I would really appreciate a JSfiddle (or similar) of your exact code so I can better tell what is wrong